# How to import functions from a submodule in a Python egg?

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

I have a custom Python egg I've written, which I cannot get the submodule (or nested module) to load externally.  I've been able to load a root-level module just fine.

Here's the obfuscated structure:

```
my_egg/
    my_egg/
        __init__.py (empty file)
        module_one.py
        my_subdir\
            __init__.py (empty file)
            module_two.py
    setup.py
```

Importing module_one works:

```
from my_egg import module_one
```

But I cannot seem to get module_two to import.  Here's what I've tried:

```
from my_egg.my_subdir import module_two
from my_egg import my_subdir.module_two
from my_egg.my_subdir.module_two import *
```

None of those worked.  Here's what my setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_egg',
  version='0.1',
  packages=['my_egg'],
  test_suite='nose.collector',
  tests_require=['nose'],
  zip_safe=False)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surpised no one answered this.  I was able to get it working after scouring Google, pulling from different sources, and trying different things.

One thing which held me up... I was trying to install my custom egg on a Databricks cluster.  And I didn't realize that once you delete a library (egg) the cluster must be restarted in order for it to be deleted.  So every time I would try changes, nothing took effect.  This definitely delayed my progress.

In any case, I changed to my `setup.py` file to use `find_packages` and made changes to the empty `__init__.py` files.  I'm not really sure if both changes were needed, or if one would've sufficed.

New `my_egg/setup.py`:

```
exec(open('my_egg/version.py').read())

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='my_egg',
      version=__version__,
      packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests', 'docs')),
      test_suite='nose.collector',
      tests_require=['nose'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

I added a `my_egg/version.py` file to help me debug if I was using the right version on the cluster.  That addition actually led me to discover that Databricks requires the cluster be restarted.

New root init `my_egg/my_egg/__init__.py` file:

```
from .version import __version__
from .module_one import module_one_func
from .my_subdir.module_two import module_two_func

__all__ = ['module_one_func']
```

New sub-dir init `my_egg/my_egg/my_subdir/__init__.py`:

```
from module_two import module_two_func

__all__ = ['module_two_func']
```